Replaying twist messages from a rosbag2 adds drift to the movement
I am working on a SLAM solution and I am simulating a robot with a planar_move plugin to control it on Gazebo. I am working on an Ubuntu 22.04 with ros2 humble. I can control the robot well with a teleop_twist_keyboard node that sends Twist messages over to the Gazebo planar_move node on a topic named /gazebo_sim/cmd_vel. The planar_move outputs an odometry message which I add noise afterwards on another node.
I am simulating on a rather complex world with corridors and lots of rooms so to make things faster I decided to record the /gazebo_sim/cmd_vel on a rosbag and then record it.
The problem comes when playing the bag, the simulated robot movement slightly does not match the one recorded, and so it misses the first door and hits a wall.
I have no idea what I can try being able to resend the commands reliably would speed up the development a lot.
